# Long polling vs short polling SQS for multiple queue processing with same lambda

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

We have a service where we created multiple customer queues (one queue per customer to process the orders separately). We have one lambda processing all the queues. We need orders to be processed immediately when they come in.

Should I go with short polling or long polling in SQS for this?

I read with long polling the lambda has to wait till the polling wait time expires. This isn't really ideal when the same lambda is processing all of my queues.

Comment: I don't think long/short polling is relevant in this situation. Long polling simply relates to the amount of a time an SQS client 'waits' before being told that there are no messages in a queue. If there are messages in a queue, then there is no wait. This isn't relevant when triggering Lambda functions from a queue. Do you have a specific problem you are trying to resolve?